# Flask error handler

Tags: python, web, flask

I created simple multi-application Flask site. I moved all errors view (404, 501, etc.) to application `errors`. But when an error occures I see only default error pages of Flask, not my own.
Structure of project is:

```
/site
|-> main.py
     from flask import Flask

     app = Flask(__name__)
     app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

     import errors, account, mysite, blog
     from errors.views import not_found

     @app.route("/")
     def index_view():
         return "Welcome!"

     @app.route("/about")
     def about_view():
         return "About"

     if __name__ == "__main__":
         app.run(debug=True)
|-> templates
  |-> errors
    |-> 404.html

|->errors
  |-> __init__.py
     from main import app
     import errors.views
  |-> views
     from errors import app
     from flask import render_template

     @app.errorhandler(404)
     def not_found(error):
         return render_template('errors/404.html'), 404
```

If i returning content of `errors/views.py` to `main.py` it begins work as expected and show me my error page.

Comment: This is said to be a "multi-application site", but there's only one application object.

Answer (score 4):

Put all the error templates like 404 etc. in the main templates folder of your project. So if your project is called "myproject", you can have something like:

```
myproject/
    __init__.py
    templates
        404.html
        503.html
        .. and so on
```

Call these in your  `__init__.py` file as:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

Comment: It is obvious but not good solution. If I adding another application to project I'll facing the same problem. That is why I want to split event error from project.

Comment: @AlexG.P. I'm just passing by and I know I'm late to the party, but a project is meant to have a single application object. If you're adding *another* application object, then you'd be better off creating a new/separate project. This answer is a good solution.